Запятые, оборот с как
Нужны ли запятые вокруг "как призывники" в предложении:
Прямо во дворе военкомата горит костер, в него мы, как призывники, бросаем свои паспорта.
По правилам это вроде подходит под "оборот тождества", и тогда запятые не нужны. Но интуитивно хочется поставить.

Правильно:
Прямо во дворе военкомата горит костер, в него мы, // как призывники,// бросаем свои паспорта.
Оборот выделен паузами.
Пояснение
Оборот имеет значение тождества, но при этом  может быть два решения — необособленное обстоятельство (в качестве призывников) или обособленный оборот с причинным значением (так как мы призывники). По структуре предложения (позиции оборота между подлежащим и сказуемым) здесь скорее значение причины (= будучи призывниками), и оборот желательно обособить.
Сравнить: Паспорта мы бросаем костер как призывникИ — они больше  недействительны. Ударная позиция оборота в конце первой части предложения.
Розенталь, § 42. Сравнительный оборот, пункт 3(1)
Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок 
причинного значения: Васенда, как человек положительный и 
практический, нашёл невыгодным закреплённое место (Пом.) — 
‘будучи человеком положительным’; Она была, как меньшая, 
любимица отца (Л. Т.) — ‘поскольку она была меньшая’; Как 
старший, приказываю вам, господа, немедленно разойтись 
(Купр.); — см. § 19, п. 7);

